# How to bound $\sum_{\ell^2 + m^2 \leq y } \tau(\ell^2 + m^2)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\tau$ be the divisor function. I would like to know how I can obtain 
$$
\sum_{\ell^2 + m^2 \leq y  } \tau(\ell^2 + m^2) \ll y \log y. 
$$
Any comments would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not going to work this out now, but I know how I would first try to show this. The sum is the same as $\sum_{n \leq y} \tau(n) r_2(n)$, where $r_2(n)$ is the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of two squares. Both $\tau$ and $\frac{1}{4} r_2$ are multiplicative, so I would examine the Euler product and see if one can recognize a double pole at $s = 1$ in the associated Dirichlet series. This is actually producing a bit more, since this would give the leading asymptotic (as opposed to merely the bound), and perhaps producing less is easier? I'm uncertain.

Comment: Do you understand davidlowryduda's solution ? $r_2(n)=4\sum_{d| n} \chi_4(d)$ (the sum of two squares theorem which follows from unique factorization in prime ideals in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$) which gives the Euler product of $\frac14 sum_n \tau(n) r_2(n)n^{-s}$. What  is it, what do you get from it.

Comment: @davidlowryduda did you mean "and perhaps producing more is easier"?

Comment: @mathworker21 He meant what he wrote, that the same tauberian theorem as in the PNT gives the asymptotic $\sim y \log y$ and it is not obvious there is an elementary way for $O(y\log y)$ that anyway nobody needs.

Comment: @reuns yes, so, in other words, producing more is easier. he said the opposite: "producing less is easier".

Comment: (I meant $\sim C y\log y$)

Comment: I understand  @davidlowryduda 's comment and I get the Euler product but I don't know how to figure out the order of the pole at $s=1$.

Comment: @reuns did u read my last comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sketch. By multiplicativity,
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\tau(n) \sum_{d \mid n} \chi_4(d)}{n^s} = \prod_p \sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\tau(p^r) \sum_{d \mid p^r} \chi_4(d)}{p^{rs}}.$$
We have that $\tau(p^r) = r + 1$, and if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, then $\sum_{d \mid p^r} \chi_4(d) = r + 1$, while if $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, then $\sum_{d \mid p^r} \chi_4(d) = 1$ if $r$ is even and $\sum_{d \mid p^r} \chi_4(d) = 0$ if $r$ is odd. Thus this is equal to
$$\prod_{p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}} \sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} (r + 1)^2 p^{-rs} \prod_{p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}} \sum_{\substack{r = 0 \\ r \equiv 0 \pmod{2}}}^{\infty} (r + 1) p^{-rs}.$$
By evaluating these geometric series,
$$\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} (r + 1)^2 p^{-rs} = \frac{1 - p^{-2s}}{(1 - p^{-s})^4} = \frac{1 - \chi_4(p) p^{-2s}}{(1 - p^{-s})^2 (1 - \chi_4(p) p^{-s})^2},$$
and
$$\sum_{\substack{r = 0 \\ r \equiv 0 \pmod{2}}}^{\infty} (r + 1) p^{-rs} = \frac{1 + p^{-2s}}{(1 - p^{-s})^2 (1 + p^{-s})^2} = \frac{1 - \chi_4(p) p^{-2s}}{(1 - p^{-s})^2 (1 - \chi_4(p) p^{-s})^2}.$$
So
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\tau(n) \sum_{d \mid n} \chi_4(d)}{n^s} = \prod_p \frac{1 - \chi_4(p) p^{-2s}}{(1 - p^{-s})^2 (1 - \chi_4(p) p^{-s})^2} = \frac{\zeta(s)^2 L(s,\chi_4)^2}{L(2s,\chi_4)}.$$
So this has a double pole at $s = 1$ due to the pole of $\zeta(s)$, whereas $L(s,\chi_4)$ is holomorphic for $\Re(s) \geq 1$. Now any Tauberian theorem will do the job, or more generally one could use Perron's formula.